# How does finding a Franklin ship change what we know about the expedition?

Tags: 19th-century, exploration, canada

An expedition to find the Franklin ships [has found one](http://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/lost-franklin-expedition-ship-found-in-the-arctic-1.2760311).

> At this point, the searchers aren't sure if they've found HMS Erebus or HMS Terror. But sonar images from the waters of Victoria Strait, just off King William Island, clearly show wreckage of a ship on the ocean floor.

What does this change? What outstanding questions are likely to be answered as a result of the discovery?

Comment: One outstanding question is addressed at the bottom of the article - whether the Inuit oral histories of the event are accurate.

Comment: Since we looked there based on the oral history, that isn't a change - we were already assuming the Inuit history was correct.

Comment: One outstanding (in the sense of unanswered, not of extraordinary) question would be where did it sink. What does finding it change? Not a whole helluva lot.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what we didn't know was where the ship, and now that we know where the ship is, we can accurately trace their journey. What used to be guesswork can now be affirmed or contradicted as the position and possible routes are syncronised.